# Photoshop trial and commercial use

Tags: adobe-photoshop, license

Is it legal to use trial version of Photoshop for commercial use? I am confused after reading this: [link](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4647207).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not according to their license terms.  For example, from the [Photoshop CS6 license](http://www.adobe.com/products/eulas/pdfs/Gen_WWCombined-MULTI-20111031_1230.pdf):

> 2.1.2.2 Evaluation Software.  The Software, or portions of the Software, that are provided with a serial number designated for "evaluation purposes" or other similar designation (such as Software or a serial number supplied as "EVAL" under a separate agreement)("Evaluation Software") may only be installed and used on Permitted Number of Compatible Computers during the License Term for demonstration, evaluation, and training purposes only, and only if any Output Files or other materials produced through such use are used only for internal, non-commercial, and non-production purposes.